# How to use angular reactive form to generate a complex JSON object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i tried many times to fix this issue, but i think your help angular developer, i'm trying to populate a json object into UI:

heres the JSON Object :

> items={"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"}]}

heres the [User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMu6Q.png) , i have a submit button in the user interface, it doesnt appear but its not a problem it can execute this function :

```
save(){
  console.log(Json.stringify(this.myForm.value))
 }
```

the Json Object generated is :

> {"tabls":[{"price":20}]}

it shows  me just the only first price, but what i want is, show prices generated in the UI in my case the json generated should be :

> {"tabls":[{"price":20},{"price":10}]}

How can i achieve this result please ?

heres the html code :

```
                  <div formArrayName="tabls">
                    <div *ngFor="let myGroup of myForm.controls.tabls.controls; let i=index">
                      <div [formGroupName]="i">

                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-4" >
                              <div   >
                                  <div class="inner-addonx left-addon header-search" style="float:left;margin-right: 4px;">
                                    <i class="glyphicon  markerx" style="border: 5px solid #FED141"></i>
                                  </div>
                                <span >{{items.departure}}</span> 

                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-1" ><img style="    width: 32px;    height: 22px;" src="../assets/img/arrow.svg" ></div>
                          <div class="col-sm-4" >
                              <span *ngIf="items.stations.length > 0">
                                  {{items.stations[0].station}}
                              </span>
                              <span *ngIf="items.stations.length === 0">
                                  {{items.arrival}}
                              </span>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-sm-3" >
                              <div class="input-group " >

                                  <input type="number" formControlName="price"  value="1000" min="0" step="1" [attr.id]="'textbox'" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="form-control currency" id="c2" /> 
                                  <span class="input-group-addon">Dhs</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>




                        <hr/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div *ngIf="items?.arrival && items?.departure">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div  style="">
                                        <div class="inner-addonx left-addon header-search" style="float:left;margin-right: 4px;">
                                            <i class="glyphicon  markerx" style="border: 5px solid #63a599"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <span>{{items.departure}}</span> 

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-1" >
                                    <img style="    width: 32px;    height: 22px;" src="../assets/img/arrow.svg" >
                                  </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4" >
                                    <div  style="">
                                        <div class="inner-addonx left-addon header-search" style="float:left;margin-right: 4px;">
                                            <i class="glyphicon  markerx" style="border: 5px solid #F53F5B"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <span>{{items.arrival}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-3" >
                                    <div class="input-group ">

                                        <input type="number" formControlName="price"  value="1000" min="0" step="1" [attr.id]="'finalprice'" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="form-control currency" id="c2" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Dhs</span>


                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
```

Typescript code :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.myForm = this._fb.group({

   tabls: this._fb.array([
    this.initArray2()
   ]),
 })
 }
initArray2() {
   return this._fb.group({
   price: [''],
  });
 }
```

Comment: as per this code your initArray returns only one price object

Comment: thanks ser for answer, so what is the solution please ?

Comment: Can you share plunkr?

Comment: see https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#display-the-formarray

Comment: or https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Comment: i know these articles, my problem is completely differente

Comment: if possible share it some where

Comment: i cant its private but i can help u if you want..do you need an extra information ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, all i get is : {"tabls":[{"price":20}]}

Comment: do you realize my problem ser ? or i can explain if you want.because its a little bit tricky

Comment: yes... <div [formGroupName]="i"> block should have only one formControlName named price;

Comment: you might need one more grouping of Controls

Comment: maybe your right..could u help me to achieve that  please

Comment: Let me ask one question, why do you need it in {"tabls":[{"price":20},{"price":10}]} format ?

Comment: my backend must have this object like this format, as a list.

Comment: {"tabls":[{"price":20},{"price":10},...........]} list of prices

Comment: only 2 rows or n rows?

Comment: n rows of cours

Comment: posting one url in answers, have a look

Comment: i dont understand ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to 2 inputs with formControlName="**price**", it 
overwrites previous value;

Comment: but what is the solution ??

Comment: because the json generated should be like this :{"tabls":[{"price":20},{"price":10}]}

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
   let lista = this.buildArray([{price:0},{price:0}]);
   this.myForm = this._fb.group({
   tabls=lista
   }):
```

}

```
buildArray(data: any[]) {
    //witch each data, we create a fbGroup 

    const arr = myArray.map(data => {
      return this.fb.group({
        "Id": [data.Id], //we can omit some control
        "betslipTeamName": [data.betslipTeamName],
        "stake": [data.stake],
      });
    });
    //And return a array of fbGroup
    return this.fb.array(arr);
  }
```

See the example completed in [Binding a text input to a property in an observable object - Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135963/binding-a-text-input-to-a-property-in-an-observable-object-angular-2) or check the multiples links about this

Comment: thanks for answer, the items={"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"}]} is dynamic thats mean i could have multiple stations otherwize multiple prices..this my problem.

Comment: my final json object could be like this :{"tabls":[{"price":20},{"price":10},...]}

Comment: @Newme, it's an example at init. you must write this.buildArray(yourdata.tabls)

Comment: i have to change  "Id": [data.Id], //we can omit some control
        "betslipTeamName": [data.betslipTeamName],
        "stake": [data.stake], by price :[] ?

Comment: but you should keep on mind that, i have n row of price not only two as mentionned here in your code : let lista = this.buildArray([{price:0},{price:0}]);